# How to take the first record of each person in a table

Tags: sql

I'm having some problems with a table.
In particular, using a query, I have a table containing several matches and for every match I have the people that used to play that match.

Every person is reported more than once because they have a "score" recorded for each day.

For example I have:

```
134 | 1958-01-02 | Johnny Carter | 1958-03-10 | 12  
134 | 1958-01-02 | Johnny Carter | 1955-02-10 | 17  
134 | 1958-01-02 | Johnny Carter | 1957-04-07 | 15  
187 | 1985-04-03 |  Denis Rouge  | 1958-03-20 | 86  
187 | 1985-04-03 |  Denis Rouge  | 1985-02-15 | 23  
187 | 1985-04-03 |  Denis Rouge  | 1985-03-07 | 17
```

And I need to take the most recent value date, so I need to have this:

```
134 | 1958-01-02 | Johnny Carter | 1957-04-07 | 15  
187 | 1985-04-03 |  Denis Rouge  | 1985-03-07 | 17
```

Comment: First _row_, not record.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "first row" or "last row" in SQL.  If you want to do anything like "first row" or "last row" of a given group of rows, the onus is on you to specify which particular ordering of rows per which you want "the first" (last).

Then it is a matter of applying Gordon Linoff's technique (valid for standard SQL) or some equivalent syntactic construct that might be DBMS-specific.

E.g. Gordon Linoff's solution takes "first row" in the assumed ordering of "descending on date".

Also, in certain cases you might have to beware that the ordering you have in mind might give ties, in which case you'd be getting back more than one row with Gordon's solution (and typically randomly chosen ones with proprietary syntaxes/constructs).  So beware that your ordering will be total.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `(id, date)`.  In many databases, this is the most efficient way of implementing this logic.

Comment: thats a good way of using corelated subquery but will not be optimal when compared to group by with having as it has to use subquery to refer the table again

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . That is simply untrue.  `GROUP BY` is generally more expensive, although in some databases they might be comparable (and some databases do not even have indexes).

Comment: Did you mean grouping with random indexes would take much longer than an extra subquery in the original select

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . I mean that with the correct index, this will typically be the most efficient way of implementing the logic.  On massive parallel databases, there might be additional considerations (such as the partitioning of the data), but `group by` is will often be less performant.

Comment: Umm.. I agree partitioning of data would make group by work a lil slow but i still dont find the difference as selecting the data again even via correct index would take extra time as compared to group by with a single select statement. Nevermind though I have shared my opinion maybe you know it better by your experience ive got to agree with your statement.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . You need to time it.  `GROUP BY` is generally slower that a `JOIN` and much slower than an index lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` with `having`

```
      SELECT COL1,max(col2) , 
       COL3,max(col4) , 
       max(col5) from 
      table group by col1, col3 having 
       max(Case when(col2=max(distinct 
        col2) then 1 else 0 end) =1 and 
        max(Case when(col4=max(distinct 
        col4) then 1 else 0 end) =1
           ;
```

Comment: Can you are select columns that are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause or aggregated?

Comment: Still looks like you have columns in your `SELECT` class that are not aggregate or part of the `GROUP BY` clause?